# C Relational Operator Output

Tags: c, logical-operators, or-operator, and-operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 0, z = 5;
    int a = x && y || z++;
    printf("%d", z);
}
```

This yields output as 6 whereas

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x = 1, y = 0, z = 5;
    int a = x && y && z++;
    printf("%d", z);
}
```

this would yield answer as 5. WHY ?? Someone please explain.

Comment: What did you expect and why?

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the [**Short Circuit mechanism**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

What this means is that when the result of a logical operator is already determined, the rest of the expression isn't evaluated at all, including potential side effects.

The first code fragment behaves like:

```
int a = (1 && 0) /* result pending... */ || z++;
```

And the second:

```
int a = (1 && 0) /* result determined */;
```

This happens because the value of a logical AND is known to be false if the left side expression is false.

Answer (score 6):

As you can probably tell, the difference between two fragments of code is that the first one evaluates `z++`, while the other one doesn't.

The reason the second code does not evaluate `z++` is that the expression ahead of it evaluates to `false`, so `&&` chain "short-circuits" the evaluation of the last term.

Operator `||`, on the other hand, would short-circuit only when the left side is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

For starters function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In the first program the initialization expression can be represented like

```
int a = ( x && y ) || ( z++ );
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 4. ...If the first operand compares **unequal to 0**, the second operand is not 
>      evaluated.

The first oerand `( x && y )` of the expression is equal to 0 because y is initialized by 0

```
int x = 1, y = 0, z = 5;
```

So the second operand `( z++ )` is evaluated.

As result z will be equal to 6.

In the second program the initialization expression can be represented the same way as in the first program

```
int a = ( x && y ) && ( z++ );
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 4. ...If the first operand compares **equal to 0**, the second operand is not 
>      evaluated.

As before the first operand `( x && y )` of the expression is equal tp 0 and according to the quote the second operand `( z++ )` is not evaluated.

As result z will be equal to 5 as before.